# Cleaning Car Window Switches?

Tags: cleaning, power-windows

I accidentally spilt a soft drink that landed directly onto the car window switches on the driver side. As you may have guessed, the switches are now very gummy given the dried sugar within...

This is generally what I have to work with and need to clean: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ALMhiXkoBKNjSZFEq6zrEVXac/Automotive-interior-styling-for-Chevrolet-Cruze-TRAX-Window-buttons-trim-decoration-accessory-7pcs-set.jpg

Is there a way to clean them out without removing the door panel?

Comment: The switch panel can be removed without removing the door panel.

Comment: Make and model of vehicle?

Comment: @Moab 2014 Chevy Cruze

Answer (score 1):

fill it with WD40, then shop vac it out.  repeat.  may take several times.  if that doesn't work, many switches can be pulled out, or the trim / bezel their in, can be pulled up. maybe one or two screws.   I would have to see your car.  Replacement switches don't cost too much.

YouTube has [this door panel removal video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBhaa_CmDT0) with the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the door switches and spray liberally with electrical cleaner then lay face down to let them dry.